# How to use Index function to locate two cells next to each other and return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to search in an array for an exact value. If the value is found, I want the function to look to the row just to the right of it to see if it matches another exact value. If both cases are true I want it to mark the currently highlighted cell with `"X"`.

I've tried using `index(match` and also the formula below utilizing `If(and` functions.

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(C8,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$369,0),MATCH($AN$1,Sheet2!$C$3:$C$369,0)),"X",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data with expected outputs? Likely easier to visualize

Answer (score 0):

Use Countifs:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B$3:$B$369,C8,Sheet2!$C$3:$C$369,$AN$1),"X",0)
```

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.